# D3 Round path stroke corners

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I've got a donut chart where I'm using the a path with stroke width to display the data. Currently it is just a path going up and down with a thick enough stroke width to make it look like a rectangle. Is there a way for me to slighly round out the corners of the stroke? So far stroke-linecap and stroke-linejoin only turn the end of the stroke into a big circle which is way more than I need. I just want the edges to not be so sharp, anyway that I can do this?

```js
// D3 code I used to create this
function drawBenefitsValues(svg, data, startArc ) {
  // data is an array that looks like [3, 3, 5, 6, 1, 2]
  const radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
  const degreesToRadians = degrees => degrees * 0.0174533;
  const innerFactor = startArc;
  const outerFactor = value => innerFactor + value * 0.04;
  const slice = degreesToRadians(30);

  data.forEach((ele, idx) => {
    const id = `gBenefits${idx}`;
    const color =
      ele.benefits > 4.5
        ? colors.green 
        : ele.benefits > 2.75
        ? colors.yellow 
        : ele.benefits < 2.75
        ? colors.red
        : colors.yellow;
        
    const angleBegins = startAngle + idx * slice;
    const gridPie = d3
      .pie()
      .startAngle(angleBegins + 0.26)
      .endAngle(angleBegins)
      .sort(null)
      .value(1);

    const arc = d3
      .arc()
      .innerRadius(radius * outerFactor(ele.benefits))
      .startAngle(d => d.startAngle)
      .outerRadius(radius * innerFactor)
      .endAngle(d => d.startAngle);

    svg
      .append("g")
      .attr("id", id)
      .selectAll(`#${id}`)
      .data(gridPie([ele]))
      .join("path")
      .attr("class", "benefits")
      .attr("fill", color)
      .attr("d", arc)
      .attr("stroke-width", "18")
      .attr("stroke", color)
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <svg viewBox="-250,-250,500,500">
    <g id="gBenefits0"><path class="benefits" fill="#E2B465" d="M-80.24920084088171,-138.41988933820105L-57.67911310438373,-99.489295461832Z" stroke-width="18" stroke="#E2B465"></path></g>
<g id="gBenefits1"><path class="benefits" fill="#999A57" d="M-0.2968618004224759,-164.99973294848522L-0.2069036790823317,-114.99981387318667Z" stroke-width="18" stroke="#999A57"></path></g>
  </svg>
</body>
```

[image]

Code sandbox link. Code can be found in wheel.js line 128
https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-keldysh-57nnd?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Why not using `rect` with rounded corners, rather than a `path`?

Comment: That was my initial thought but me being new to d3 and creating svgs I wasn't sure how to create one that would render around a pie.

Comment: @Mehdi would you happen to have an example of doing this on an arc?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] so we can see what the problem is.

Comment: I added the code snippet that runs the svg as well as the code sandbox showing the entire wheel using d3 and what file and line to find it in. Sorry, I’m not sure what else I could add to it to help you visualize it.